# Python Serial library for RaspberryPi2 tutorial/command list

Tags: python, serial, bluetooth, script

I have a problem with using the UART on RPi2.

I tried every program found on the internet but nothing works. I checked every baud rate of my two BT modules but whatever code I use I've got errors like this:

Error 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Serial2.py", line 6, in
<module>
    serial_line = ser.readline()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 449, in
read
    buf = os.read(self.fd, size-len(read)) OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Error 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Serial2.py", line 6, in <module>
    serial_line = ser.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 449, in read
    buf = os.read(self.fd, size-len(read))
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Error 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Serial.py", line 7, in
<module>
    rcv = port.read()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 456, in
read
    raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)')
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read
but returned no data (device disconnected?)
```

Err1 code:

```
import serial

    port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)

    while True:
        port.write("\r\nSay something:")
        rcv = port.read()
        port.write("\r\nYou sent:" + rcv)
```

Err2&3 code:

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)

while 1:
    serial_line = ser.readline()

    print(serial_line)
    time.sleep(300)
ser.close()
```

I'm using ArduinoRC app (Terminal) to send data.

Would you help me and/or send a link to a good command list please ?

Comment: You want to communicate between a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino using serial data.  You have a cable to connect the Pi and Arduino.  To what do you connect the Pi end of the cable?  To what do you connect the Arduino end of the cable?

Comment: No! I want to communicate between smartphone>>>bluetooth>>>RPi using BT module on serial in RPi.

Comment: It's working with Arduino but not with BTM222 module.

Comment: And it stopped working with Ardu... :/

Comment: What do you think ? Is it a problem with RPi UART lanes ?

Comment: The most likely fault is in the wiring.  Could you post a photo of the connections you have made between the Pi and the bluetooth unit and could you also describe the connections?

Comment: Today I disconnected everything and now I'm reinstalling Raspbian, because something weird happened - the same program stopped reading serial library, whaaa ?!....

Comment: I reinstalled everything. Script is reading every library properly. I changed wires too. I tried to test out everything again with arduino. RPi is sending the data and Arduino executes proper piece of code but RPi don't recieve data. This is my photos: http://i61.tinypic.com/ak7bpy.jpg | http://i57.tinypic.com/1zgrjmg.jpg | http://i60.tinypic.com/2m76ib9.jpg .

Comment: And that is re-writed code: import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import serial
import time
import sys

port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=100)

BOARD=GPIO.BOARD
OUT=GPIO.OUT
HIGH=GPIO.HIGH
LOW=GPIO.LOW

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, OUT)

port.write('1')

if(port.read() == '1'):
 GPIO.output(11, HIGH)
 time.sleep(1)
 GPIO.output(11, LOW)
 time.sleep(1)
else:
 print "Fail"
 port.write('0')

Comment: You can edit your post and add that formatted code.

Comment: It won't be necessary anymore. Everything is working.

Comment: One time it's ok, next time it's not. I must buy new wires. If this won't help I'll buy second RPi2, I'll need another one anyway so It won't be wasted money, thanks for trying to help ")

Answer (score 1):

I also had a lot of problems with it... But today I found a solution from this site: http://m.instructables.com/id/Read-and-write-from-serial-port-with-Raspberry-Pi/

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time 
import serial 

ser = serial.Serial( port='/dev/ttyUSB0', 
    baudrate = 9600, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, 
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, 
    timeout=1 
) 
counter=0

while 1: 
    x=ser.readline() 
    print x
```

And the code worked, only you need to change the

```
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

To:

```
/dev/ttyAMA0
```

Like this (this is the code that worked):

EDIT: reformatted the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0.2
)
counter=0

while 1:
    x=ser.readline()
    print x
```

Ps: I used an HC-06 module, also be sure you have disabled the boot sequence on the serial port: open terminal,
    sudo raspi-config

And then go to advanced options and there will be something like boot on serial, you need to disable that.

Kind regards 
Michielvk

Comment: Can you reformat the code - there is some indentation missing which I think python *will* regard as significant and thus will not run properly without.

Comment: I reformatted the code.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://download.chip45.com/BTM222_DataSheet.pdf
the factory settings of the UART are as follows

```
Baud rate: 19200 bps
Data bit: 8
Parity: none
Stop bit: 1
```

Comment: So what ? I programmed the same baudrate in my newest python script and BT module. With arduino everything is working (Ardu&Bluetooth, Pi&Arduino) but I can't force Pi to work with Bluetooth.